# How to merge angular datatables functionalities with jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I want to make use of the angular datatable functionalities in my jhipster datatable. I have followed the docs on angular datatable meticulously but it does not display any of the functionalities on the UI.

```
angular.json
     "styles": [
        "scss",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
      ]
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
 imports: [ DataTablesModule ];
```

app.component.ts

```
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};


this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 5,
  lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25],
  processing: true
};
```

app.component.html

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm row-border hover" datatable 
  [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><span>Transaction ID</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
    <th scope="col"><span>Transaction </span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
    <th scope="col"><span>Applicant </span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
    <th scope="col"><span>Transaction Number</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
    <th scope="col"><span>Transaction Creation Date</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon> 
    </th>
    <th scope="col"><span>Transaction Status</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let trans of data">
    <td> 
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ trans?.createdBy }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ trans?.transactionType }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ trans?.transactionNumber }}
    </td>
    <td>{{ trans.createDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}</td>
    <td>
      <span ng-if="trans.status">{{ trans.status }}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which version of JHipster? If nothing renders, it's probably that CSS are not loaded. What do you see in browser's console? Have you tried what is described your project's README.md about vendor.scss ?

Comment: The version of the jhipster is 6.5.1 . There is no error on the browser's console and there is no place in the project (angular datatable) where you have to import any link at all in the vendor.scss file.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to me that the 2 CSS stylesheets that you added to `angular.json` in `styles` array are the ones to import in `vendor.scss`. JHipster 6 was not perfectly integrated with Angular CLI, so changes in angular.json had usually no effect. This has been fixed in JHipster 7.

Comment: Okay. Please can you give me an example of how to write import statements for the stylesheets from the node_modules folder on vendor.scss. that means angular.json does not also recognize the scripts

Comment: Yes probably, as I said the example is in your project's README.md it's the example about leaflet library.

Comment: Thanks. It did not work. I will search for another alternative

Comment: "It did not work" is not very informative. Anyway, jquery datables is not the most popular tabular components for Angular, I usually prefer using PrimeNG as a whole UI library or ag-grid if you only want a table.

Comment: Also, you should consider upgrading to JHipster 7 in order to benefit from better Angular CLI integration.

Comment: Ag-grid merged perfectly . Much Gratitude!!